# Helping with review tasks

Tags: discussion, reviewing

I just saw that most of the reviewing is done by moderators. However the idea of StackExchange is that the [moderation is done by you](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/). While we as moderators should have some final opinion, the idea is that users of the site discuss and come to conclusions. Thatswhy I'd like to ask anyone who has a [certain reputation](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), to go to the [review queue](https://tor.stackexchange.com/review) and have a look at open issues. You can vote to close certain questions, you can decide how to handle first questions and do lots of other things. This helps to improve our site and hopefully to attract new users. If you have any questions, please use the Meta site. We'll happily answer them.

Just for the record: I will stop for a while doing review tasks myself, because I think this should be done by the community. Currently the mods do too much review work and their votes are absolute and final. The theory is that such things should come from the community and be subject for discussion.

Answer (score 5):

I've been in a similar boat for a while myself. Admittedly I've been a bit distracted the past few months, but I generally try to skip the "First Posts" and "Suggested Edits" queues and focus mainly on the more *advanced* queues related to close votes and comment moderation.

So yes, I second Jens' motion for everybody to help this more of a community effort!